# Beautiful soup, how to scrape multiple urls and save them in a csv file

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am wondering how to scrape multiple websites/urls and save them, (the data), to a csv file. I can only save the first page right now. I have tried many different ways but it doesn´t seem to work. How can I save 5 pages in a csv file and not only one?

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
import time

 urls = ['https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1&page=1', 'https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1&page=2', 'https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1&page=3', 'https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1&page=4','https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1&page=5']

for url in urls:   
    my_url = requests.get(url) 
    html = my_url.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

    data = []
    ts = time.time()
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 

    for container in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'responsive_search_name_combined'}):
        title = container.find('span',attrs={'class':'title'}).text

        if container.find('span',attrs={'class':'win'}):
            win = '1'
        else:
            win = '0'

        if container.find('span',attrs={'class':'mac'}):
            mac = '1'
        else:
            mac = '0'

        if container.find('span',attrs={'class':'linux'}):
            linux = '1'
        else:
            linux = '0'

        data.append({
            'Title':title.encode('utf-8'),
            'Time':st,
            'Win':win,
            'Mac':mac,
            'Linux':linux})

with open('data.csv', 'w',encoding='UTF-8', newline='') as f:
    fields = ['Title','Win','Mac','Linux','Time']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fields)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
testing = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
heading = testing.head(100)
discription = testing.describe()
print(heading)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was apparently very blind to my code, that can happen when you stare at it all day. All I actually had to do was to move the "data = []" above the for loop so it wouldn´t reset every time.

Comment: happens to everyone. sometimes just fresh eyes looking at something goes a long way. I also implimented pandas instead of csv to write to csv. Some people think it's overkill, but honestly I'm just fomfortable using pandas

Answer (score 2):

the issue is you are re-initializing your data after each url. And then writing it after the very last iteration, meaning you'll always just have whatever the last data you got from the last url. You'll need to have that data appending and not be overwritten after each iteration:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
import time

urls = ['https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1&page=1', 'https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1&page=2', 'https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1&page=3', 'https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1&page=4','https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1&page=5']

results_df = pd.DataFrame() #<-- initialize a results dataframe to dump/store the data you collect after each iteration
for url in urls:   
    my_url = requests.get(url) 
    html = my_url.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

    data = []  #<-- your data list is "reset" after each iteration of your urls
    ts = time.time()
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 

    for container in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'responsive_search_name_combined'}):
        title = container.find('span',attrs={'class':'title'}).text

        if container.find('span',attrs={'class':'win'}):
            win = '1'
        else:
            win = '0'

        if container.find('span',attrs={'class':'mac'}):
            mac = '1'
        else:
            mac = '0'

        if container.find('span',attrs={'class':'linux'}):
            linux = '1'
        else:
            linux = '0'

        data.append({
            'Title':title,
            'Time':st,
            'Win':win,
            'Mac':mac,
            'Linux':linux})

        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data) #<-- temporary storing the data in a dataframe
        results_df = results_df.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True) #<-- dumping that data into a results dataframe


results_df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False) #<-- writing the results dataframe to csv

testing = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
heading = testing.head(100)
discription = testing.describe()
print(heading)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results_df)
     Linux Mac ...                                      Title Win
0        0   0 ...            Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six® Siege   1
1        0   0 ...            Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six® Siege   1
2        1   1 ...                    Total War: WARHAMMER II   1
3        0   0 ...            Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six® Siege   1
4        1   1 ...                    Total War: WARHAMMER II   1
5        0   1 ...                                  Frostpunk   1
6        0   0 ...            Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six® Siege   1
7        1   1 ...                    Total War: WARHAMMER II   1
8        0   1 ...                                  Frostpunk   1
9        1   1 ...                         Two Point Hospital   1
10       0   0 ...            Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six® Siege   1
11       1   1 ...                    Total War: WARHAMMER II   1
12       0   1 ...                                  Frostpunk   1
13       1   1 ...                         Two Point Hospital   1
14       0   0 ...                        Black Desert Online   1
15       0   0 ...            Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six® Siege   1
16       1   1 ...                    Total War: WARHAMMER II   1
17       0   1 ...                                  Frostpunk   1
18       1   1 ...                         Two Point Hospital   1
19       0   0 ...                        Black Desert Online   1
20       1   1 ...                       Kerbal Space Program   1
21       0   0 ...            Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six® Siege   1
22       1   1 ...                    Total War: WARHAMMER II   1
23       0   1 ...                                  Frostpunk   1
24       1   1 ...                         Two Point Hospital   1
25       0   0 ...                        Black Desert Online   1
26       1   1 ...                       Kerbal Space Program   1
27       1   1 ...                          BioShock Infinite   1
28       0   0 ...            Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six® Siege   1
29       1   1 ...                    Total War: WARHAMMER II   1
   ...  .. ...                                        ...  ..
1595     0   0 ...            VEGAS Pro 14 Edit Steam Edition   1
1596     0   0 ...                                       ABZU   1
1597     0   0 ...                              Sacred 2 Gold   1
1598     0   0 ...                              Sakura Bundle   1
1599     1   1 ...                                   Distance   1
1600     0   0 ...               LEGO® Batman™: The Videogame   1
1601     0   0 ...                               Sonic Forces   1
1602     0   0 ...                  The Stronghold Collection   1
1603     0   0 ...                                 Miscreated   1
1604     0   0 ...                         Batman™: Arkham VR   1
1605     1   1 ...                          Shadowrun Returns   1
1606     0   0 ...               Upgrade to VEGAS Pro 16 Edit   1
1607     0   0 ...               Girl Hunter VS Zombie Bundle   1
1608     0   1 ...                Football Manager 2019 Touch   1
1609     0   1 ...   Total War: NAPOLEON - Definitive Edition   1
1610     1   1 ...                           SteamWorld Dig 2   1
1611     0   0 ...                Condemned: Criminal Origins   1
1612     0   0 ...                          Company of Heroes   1
1613     0   0 ...           LEGO® Batman™ 2: DC Super Heroes   1
1614     1   1 ...         Euro Truck Simulator 2 Map Booster   1
1615     0   0 ...                         Sonic Adventure DX   1
1616     0   0 ...                           Worms Armageddon   1
1617     1   1 ...                       Unforeseen Incidents   1
1618     0   0 ...  Warhammer 40,000: Space Marine Collection   1
1619     0   0 ...            VEGAS Pro 14 Edit Steam Edition   1
1620     0   0 ...                                       ABZU   1
1621     0   0 ...                              Sacred 2 Gold   1
1622     0   0 ...                              Sakura Bundle   1
1623     1   1 ...                                   Distance   1
1624     0   0 ...                           Worms Revolution   1

[1625 rows x 5 columns]
```